# Increase text size on oled (Cortex M3, Stellaris LM3S6965)

Tags: c, text, cortex-m

I'm working with Cortex M3, Stellaris® LM3S6965 Evaluation Board. I'm trying to display text on the oled screen which is working. But I don't know how to increase the text size.

Does anybody know how to do that?

My current code:

```
    #include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/debug.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "drivers/rit128x96x4.h"


//*****************************************************************************
//
// The error routine that is called if the driver library encounters an error.
//
//*****************************************************************************
#ifdef DEBUG
void
__error__(char *pcFilename, unsigned long ulLine)
{
}
#endif

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Display scrolling text plus graphics on the OLED display.
//
//*****************************************************************************
int
main(void)
{
    unsigned long ulRow, ulCol, ulWidth, ulHeight;
    volatile int iDelay;
    unsigned char *pucRow;
    static char pucHello[] =
    {
        "                      "
        "Current selected timezone: +2 GMT - Brussels"
        "                      "
    };

    //
    // Set the clocking to run directly from the crystal.
    //
    SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_1 | SYSCTL_USE_OSC | SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                   SYSCTL_XTAL_8MHZ);

    //
    // Initialize the OLED display.
    //
    RIT128x96x4Init(1000000);

    // Simple scrolling text display
    //
    ulCol = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        //
        // Display the text.
        //
        RIT128x96x4StringDraw(&pucHello[ulCol++], 8, 8, 11);

        //
        // Delay for a bit.
        //
        for(iDelay = 0; iDelay < 100000; iDelay++)
        {
        }

        //
        // Wrap the index back to the beginning of the string.
        //
        if(ulCol > 53)
        {
            ulCol = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would assume your fonts are described in `"drivers/rit128x96x4.h"`. Look for other headers that look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee that you can, of course.

Embedded systems typically don't have very much freedom when it comes to font usage; dynamic scaling is pretty expensive and many fonts are handles as pre-rendered binary bitmaps of a specific size.

You need to look in the API:s defined by the `rit128x96x4.h` header, since that seems to be the display-specific functionality.

You don't say how large the font you're currently getting is; on a display as small as 128x96, I wouldn't expect there to be any super-large fonts since in general it would be more useful to provide a small font to maximize the amount of text you can fit on the screen.

**UPDATE**: If [this random Google hit](http://code.google.com/p/lm3s8962-example/source/browse/trunk/examples/4_gui_tetris/rit128x96x4.h?r=15) is accurate, the graphics API provided is not exactly rich, and there seems to be no way of switching fonts.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number for fonts in the grlib\fonts folder under StellarisWare. You can change the font by using the API call GrContextFontSet()

Answer (score 1):

The fonts are normally just arrays of bitmaps.  You can redefine the bitmaps for whatever font you want.  If you want to increase the size then there may be other constants you also need to alter so the drawing routines know how to space the characters as they are rendered.